# Run Serverside function from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have the below function("getValues"), that is supposed to execute a server side function (GetCharges)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function getValues() {
         var response = <%GetCharges%> 
         document.getElementById(("<%=txtcharge.ClientID%>")).value = response;}

}   </script>
```

When I run this, I get "undefined" in the html control.

Comment: You should definitely avoid terms like "urgently" here...

Comment: You can not directly run server side code from a web browser. There needs to be some kind of request back the server. In this instance, you should look at using AJAX. There are plenty of AJAX tutorials out there for the different flavours of ASP.net. Perhaps start here: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Comment: Noted, please am sorry, am new to this community

Answer (score -1):

What you actually want to ask is "how do I create a Rest API?".

A Rest API is basically your own web server that you create e.g. in Node.js using the Express framework (google it, i'm using it and it's awesome). What you then do in your website is an Ajax call (e.g. using jQuery's function $.ajax(...)) to access a URL on your web server. This will trigger a function on your server and your server will send back a JSON formatted response that your website can use.

Another alternative is if you use the archaic way of doing things where you e.g. create a C++ executable in your websites cgi folder and have your website run that function, just note that this is a massively outdated approach to this sort of issue that doesn't work that well, mostly because you have a lot more code to maintain in a language you don't use as frequently (since you're busy making your website's javascript code). It's better to use Node.js and a Rest API because then you can stick to javascript and get better at that instead, plus it's 100 times easier to use.

Comment: I don't think recommending a completely different server side technology stack is a good answer here. What the OP needs is available in their current technology stack. However, going into a tutorial in AJAX and ASP.net web methods is outside the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: Agree with the above feedback. Moreover there is so much to learn in the Node environment that it is not clear-cut whether it is easier to learn than anything in the .net ecosystem. _And_ we don't do platform/language wars here!